Is there a way for me to gather all the times that users from a given group have activated assigned roles in AzureAD?
I am currently working on trying to organise some groups and what their respective eligible and active roles are, and I have been able to do that so far.
Here is an example of what I have done so far
But what I would like to know now is if there is a way, either through Graph API or Powershell, to extract the information on who activated those roles and when in relation to that given group. Is that even possible?
Thank you.
I have tried researching, but I didn't find anything concrete. Tried some Powershell commands, but probably not using them well (like: Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs).

Use this query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDisplayName eq 'Add member to role in PIM completed (permanent)' and targetResources/any(t:t/id eq 'GroupID')

Assigned Cloud App Security Administrator eligible role to the group:

To fetch the details of who assigned the eligible role to the Group, make use of below Microsoft Graph query to filter audit logs:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDisplayName eq 'Add eligible member to role in PIM completed (permanent)' and targetResources/any(t:t/id eq 'GroupID')


Now I activated the role:

To fetch details of who activated the role with respect to Group ID make use of below Microsoft Graph query to filter audit logs:


The Audit log data looks like below:

To do the same in PowerShell make use of below script:
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Reports

Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter  "activityDisplayName eq 'Add member to role in PIM completed (permanent)' and targetResources/any(t:t/id eq 'GroupID')"

